# No EJB receiver available for handling after some time

Tags: jboss, ejb

I am using Jboss 7.1 Final. I have setup remote ejb using jboss-ejb-client.properties and standalone.xml accordingly. But after the server running for sometime it will throw this exception while trying to lookup the remote ejb. Is there anything I need to set in the jboss-ejb-client.properties in order for it to work. Note that I already defined the HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL, is that not enough?

Here is the properties file:

```
endpoint.name=client-endpoint

remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=222.222.23.222
remote.connection.default.port=4447
remote.connection.default.username=us
remote.connection.default.password=ps
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.jboss.remoting3.RemotingOptions.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL=60000
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no takers to this question, I found some possible solutions by googling. It might be that I have been opening too many connections by calling new InitialContext() -- I might be calling it every few minutes!!! See this link: 
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/222883

In there someone mentioned GC and the connection closing etc. That might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How do you lookup to your EJB from your EJB Client ? Incase you are using java:/ namespace the problem will happen.

Please use ejb:/ namespace to eliminate the problem.